# Win 10 Task Scheduler with Microsoft Account

Tags: windows-10, task-scheduler

I'm running Windows 10 Pro and have a local admin account. I've set up several tasks in Task Scheduler that are set to "Run whether user is logged on or not" along with "Run with highest Privileges". The local account logon credentials were entered These tasks run fine when logged on or logged off of my local admin account.

I had to log in with a Microsoft account and none of those tasks will run. Tasks that do not require "Run whether user is logged on or not" run fine.
I though that I might have to enter new account credentials for the "Run whether user is logged on or not" tasks but don't see a way to do this. It won't accept an email address and the MS account  password doesn't work.
How to I create a new scheduled task in Task Scheduler when logged in via my Microsoft account?
Many thanks,, Dave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For username, following example by Thomas, the format is pcname\username, you can check your username by running `whoami` at command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Thomas>whoami
MyPC\Thomas
```

If you use a valid username but still getting an error message `"Task Scheduler cannot apply your changes. The user account is unknown, the password is incorrect, or the user account does not have permission to modify the task."`, it means the password that you keyed-in was incorrect. You shouldn't use your local account password.

I was able to use the username (pcname\username) and my Microsoft account password to create a schedule task.

Comment: Note that if your Windows login is linked to your Microsoft Live account, the password is the one for the Microsoft Live ID, the password for the local user is known as PIN.

Answer (score 0):

In my case specifying the username as pcname\username (e.g. MyPC\Thomas) worked.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I used the format that Thomas suggested with my local account password and get a window that says: "Task Scheduler cannot apply your changes. The user account is unknown, the password is incorrect, or the user account does not have permission to modify the task."